# Identifying JavaFX Tabs

Tags: tabs, javafx

In my JFX application I created an array list to keep track of tabs. I am mostly trying to know which tabs get closed by the user so that I deal with the changes that will take place because of removing the specific tab.

I tried to use the code below to remove the closed tab from the array list. I use a `setOnClosed` method to trigger this code:
    `String id = closedTab.getId();` (this ID is assigned when the tab is created the first time, so it is not null.)

```
for (Tab aTab : allTabsList) {
    if (aTab.getId().equals(id)) {
        allTabsList.remove(aTab);
        break;
    }
}
```

I get a null pointer exception on the `getId` method. not sure why.

So I tried to do this, which kind of works:

```
for (Tab aTab : allTabsList) {
    if (aTab.equals(closedTab)) {
        allTabsList.remove(closedTab);
        if allTabsList.contains(closedTab){
            System.out.println("tab is still there");
        }
    }
}
```

After removing, I did a check if the arrayList contains this tab, and it code does not step into the if statement, so it should not have it. However, the array list size does not change.

Any ideas?

Comment: OK I found a solution with help from a friend this morning. Using the event.getSource() gets me the right object, and it gets removed properly from the arrayList.! and I found that getID() is for CSS styling. which I never defined in the FXML. that is why it returns null. :D all good!

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: I found yet another way to do it through userData. Here is the latest solution. I also wrapped the javafx tab inside a mytab object. I may change that. But here is the solution below!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually fond a better method. Here it is:

The setting is like this:

- I created a "MyTab" class to wrap the JavafX Tab object. I thought wrapping it will give me some controls of embedding fields easily. The javaFX Tab variable is named below: fxTab.
- The fxTab gets its content from a separate FXML file. In the code below, the root of the content/scene is "sceneRoot". This way, I can create multiple fxTab (part of the functionality in my program).
- Then I created an ID variable for the MyTab object and also passed it on to the fxTab through the fxTab.serUserData();
- Then I add a setOnClosed method and use the ID to identify, which fxTab was closed, and then remove its wrapper from the arrayList (allMyTabs). When closing a fxTab, i look for all MyTab objects in my arrayList, and compare the userData to identify which objects I need. Of course, the ID variables is always incremented. So there will be no tabs with similar ID.

  ```
      sceneRoot = (AnchorPane) loader.load();//load the tab scene root from the FXML loader
      Tab fxTab = new Tab();
      fxTab.setContent(sceneRoot);//add the tab scene root node to the tab
      fxTab.setClosable(true);//make the tab closable

      fxTab.setId(ID.toString());//set its ID.

      //add a close action to the created tab stage
      fxTab.setOnClosed(new EventHandler<Event>() {
          @Override
          public void handle(Event t) {
              Tab fxTab = (Tab) t.getSource();//get the source of the action...

              for (MyTab myTabObj: allMyTabs) {
                  if (myTabObj.ID.equals(fxTab.getUserData())) {
                      fxTab = myTabObj;//f so, this is the one
                      break;//break the loop
                  }

              }
              allMyTabs.remove(myTabObj);
              System.out.println("You closed Tab: " + fxTab.getUserData());
              System.out.println("Total number of remaining tabs is:" + allMyTabs.size());
          }
      });
  ```